# Setting outbound 'Expires:' in Squid server's HTTP header

Tags: http-headers, squid

I'm having a problem where items served by my Squid server are being cached by Limelight for too long, sometimes days.  It happens when a piece of content has been static for a long time (weeks) and then undergoes numerous changes in a matter of hours.

Limelight gets its content from our Squid server and I'm told that if I can add 'Expires: 15m' in the HTTP header the Squid server sends, Limelight will not cache the image for more than 15 min.

Unfortunately, I can fond no setting in Squid that will allow me to add this to the header.

Here's the HTTP header as presently being sent:

> ```
> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
> Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2009 23:57:33 GMT
> Server: nginx/0.5.26
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
> Content-Length: 83843   
> Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Dec 2009 23:52:00 GMT
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> Age: 450
> X-Cache: HIT from squid01.prod.mydomain
> X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from squid01.prod.mydomain:3128
> Via: 1.0 squid01.prod.mydomain:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE14)
> Connection: close
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the header on the origin server, not on your Squid box.

See:
  http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#IMP-SERVER